# If $g(x) = \sqrt{10 − x}$ What is the Domain for $(g\circ g)(x) = g(g(x))$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the domain for $10 − \sqrt{10 − x} ≥$ ?

Answer (score 3):

The expression you need to compute the domain of is
$$
g(g(x)=\sqrt{10-g(x)}=\sqrt{10-\sqrt{10-x}}
$$
Thus you have two conditions to fulfill:
\begin{cases}
10-x\ge0\\[1ex]
10-\sqrt{10-x}\ge0
\end{cases}
The first condition is equivalent to $x\le 10$; the second one to
$$
\sqrt{10-x}\le 10
$$
that can be squared, because both sides are surely non negative:
$$
10-x\le 100
$$
So the answer is…

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer*: This is an answer to the question in the title. I'm not sure what the question in the body is asking. 
Note 
$$
g(g(x)) = \sqrt{10-\sqrt{10-x}}
$$
The domain of $g(g(x))$ in *this context* is precisely the set of real numbers such that:
$$
\sqrt{10-x} \le 10 \text{ and } x\le 10
$$
So the domain is:
$$
10\ge x \ge -90
$$

Comment: Keep in mind that I am a pre-calculus student.

Answer (score -2):

$\sqrt{10-x}\le10$ gives $x\ge-90$ but be carefull $x\le10$ must be hold.

Comment: My answer is EXACTLY the same as above, and I give it sooner, more precise just to help a person as soon as possible; unfortunately, voted on delete. IT IS NOT FAIR

Comment: This answer unfortunately only gives the solution without any context as to how to arrive at it. I did not downvote, but I think that the OP would be better served with guidance on how to find the solution, rather than the solution itself.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you; but why vote on delete?